# How to apply new changes without dropping current data in the db.(Playframework evaluations)

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2, evaluation, play-slick

I'm using play 2.2.1 with scala. And I have a managing database evaluations. When I run my application with changes on the database, it'll drop all my datas. 
At this moment `evaluationplugin = disabled` is comment in. If I comment out, it does not apply my changes.

    For example. I have a `users` table and there are `id`, `f_name`, `l_name`

```
User
id   f_name  l_name
1.   khazo   rasp
```

And I want to add `age` field to this table without losing data. I've added this field in scala files.It works properly. I'm    assuming I need to write script in 1.sql for some `alter` command, but I don't want to write script.

How to apply new changes without dropping current data in the db. I've read [this documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/Evolutions). Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you want to have a default value when creating a new field to the table?

Comment: I solved this problem.

Comment: Great. Please put the details on how you solved your problem and accept it as answer. It may be useful for someone else. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I've added this field in scala files

In slick (you have the tag `play-slick`), you can specify a default value in your `Table`

See the documentation [here](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.0/lifted-embedding.html), under `Tables`:

```
Default[T](defaultValue: T)
    Specify a default value for inserting data the table without this column. This information is only used for creating DDL statements so that the database can fill in the missing information.
```

I am not sure if it gets translated to `ALTER` statement if the table already exists . You will have to test it.

Comment: I've added default value, but it did not help. `def age = column[Int]("Age", O.Default(0))`. Whatever it drops old data.